# Which is the best approach to implement a font size selector within the game in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will try to explain my situation the best I can:

**Context:** I'm making a smartphone game. I want to implement a text size selector in my game's options. Just the text, not the UI, I have handled the dynamic size already. Since I'm a newbie in Unity developing I don't know the best practices on how to do this.

As far as I know, the steps of this process would be the following:

1. User selects a new font size
2. An event is thrown
3. DDOL Script handles the event by applying the new size

**Questions:**

**1. Is there a way to apply the font size to all UI components directly or do I have to access every object to apply it?**

**2. How do I save this changes to persist in the game?**

I have tried to handle the event by saving the new size in PlayerPref and then apply it in every UI prefab component. As i see it, this is very unefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create a class that sets them on all Text objects.
   LeanLocalization is an asset that handles localisation but is a good example I. How you could implement this.

Here is a code example. You set the desired text size in the editor here. So if you want to do it in a build you would need to change that method but I think this gives you an idea.

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// This component will manage the text size of all SizeControlledText components
/// </summary>
[ExecuteInEditMode] //if you want to use it in editor
public class SizeControllerText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int size = 20;
    public static event System.Action OnSizeChanged;

    [SerializeField]
    private int _targetSize = 10;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _updateInEditeMode = true;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!_updateInEditeMode)
            return;
        
        if (_targetSize != size)
        {
            size = _targetSize;
            OnSizeChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

/// <summary>This component will update text size</summary>
[ExecuteInEditMode]
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class SizeControlledText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text _targetText;
    private int _currentSize;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _targetText = GetComponent<Text>();
        _currentSize = _targetText.fontSize;
    }

    public void UpdateSize()
    {
        var size = SizeControllerText.size;
        if (_currentSize == size || _targetText == null)
            return;

        _currentSize = size;
        _targetText.fontSize = size;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        SizeControllerText.OnSizeChanged += UpdateSize;

        UpdateSize();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SizeControllerText.OnSizeChanged -= UpdateSize;
        UpdateSize();
    }
}
```

2. Save it to PlayerPreferences which is easy and quick to implement. In windows this gets stored in the registry. Store all your settings in a file like a json if you know you will need more settings.

Comment: Should I then use that class to find those Text object by tag/type or should I pass all those objects as parameters in the script?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a code example that works and gives you a starting point.